# Should there be a space between if and parentheses?

Tags: php

Is there there supposed to be a space, between the eg. `if` and parentheses in statements?
Like:

```
if(something)
```

or:

```
if (something)
```

Comment: What do you mean "supposed to be"? You don't *need* it, it's merely style. The parser will tell you if you missed something that's supposed to be there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This kind of whitespace doesn't matter. It's up to personal preferences. Various open-source projects will usually define rules for code formatting, and you might want to if you're working in a team, but if you're working alone, just do whatever you like most.

Comment: Style guides are not limited to *open-source* projects.

Comment: @Quentin indeed, it was merely an example. I am open to rephrasing suggestions :)

Comment: The PSR-2 explicitly answers this question: Yes, it is. 
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#51-if-elseif-else

Answer (score 7):

you can use it either way. But keeping a standard coding style will help you make code that can be easily understood by other programmers.

Some of which are specified here.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

Comment: Another good source for code style is https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Answer (score 5):

it doesn't make a difference, but in my opinion if you put the space, then you're a bad person.

Comment: And I think the opposite.

Comment: 'if' isn't a function. It's a reserved word. Use the space.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference either way. The if statement will work just fine either way.

if(something) vs. if (something) is identical!

Personally, I prefer adding the white space in as I think it looks a lot nicer. That's just me though. Everyone has different preferences.